# Javascript equivalent to PHP __construct?

Tags: javascript

I can't find a set of google search terms that answer this question. Is there a javascript equivalent to PHP's __construct function, i.e. a function that runs automatically whenever the object is instantiated?

```
var pizza = {
    var crust,
    ** instantiate? **: function(){
        this.crust = true;
    },
    topping: function(myTopping){
        this.crust += myTopping;
    },
    bake: function(){
        alert('done!');
    }
}

var mypizza = new pizza(); // << crust is added right away, internally
mypizza.topping('pepperoni');
mypizza.topping('green pepper');
mypizza.topping('onion');
mypizza.bake();
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? You can't call an object like that, or declare variables inside an object literal.

Comment: Not this code, no. It's just a tossoff to ask the question.

Comment: Well, we expect examples being syntactically valid too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constructor() inside javascript classes for the same use.

Sample:

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {  // Constructor
    this.carname = brand;
  }
}
mycar = new Car("Ford");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

```
class Pizza {
  constructor() {
    this.crust = true;
  }
}

const pizza = new Pizza();
```

More information on constructor is available here for your reading

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor